# Interpret UMAP distances with a single cluster

Tags: bioinformatics, umap

I have a question regarding the distances between points (RNASeq samples) within a single UMAP cluster. 
As far as I have understood, the distances between clusters can not be measured in a specific distance value. However I wonder if in my case the shape of a single cluster can be interpreted. As an example, the shown cluster forms kind of a triangle and I know there is a underlying direction (cell differentiation indicated by dark to light colored blue).

Now is it valid to assume that the dark points are more different to each other (e.g. more diverse genes or higher variance in gene expression) than the light points, which are all packed more closely together? 
How can the "width" (red arrows) of the leftmost and rightmost dark points be quantified and compared to the same in the light points (dispersion along the changing value)? 
So basically to show that the difference between samples reduces along the increasing value.

These are not single cells but instead individual bulk RNA samples. So would it also be possible that with more data points new clusters at both ends of the shape would form and the distanced would again be relative?

Thank you for your help!

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to say more about the data and what you are trying to learn from them. To my eyes, at least, it looks like this might be a collection of clusters that just aren't well distinguished in this relatively small number of samples. It seems a bit unusual to use UMAP for bulk RNAseq data; was standard principal components analysis uninformative? Also, distances in UMAP can be affected by how the model was initialized; see [this bioRxiv paper](https://doi.org/10.1101/2019.12.19.877522). So, please also edit the question to explain your specific UMAP implementation.